# Backface visibility on Firefox and Bootstrap 4 carousel

Tags: css, firefox, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a website that has a Bootstrap 4 slider (carousel), I had some problem in Chrome because I got a blurry text when I activated the slider.

I solved this problem on Chrome with this code:

```
.carousel-item {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: unset!important;
    backface-visibility: unset!important;
}
```

but now I got an issue on Firefox. The slider doesn't slide well.

This is my website on my test machine:

http://www.matrix-test.com/roofing/

and as you can see in Firefox there is a problem.

Comment: Which versions of each browser are you using?  I just opened your test site in both Chrome (62.0.3202.94) and Firefox (57.0) and it looks exactly the same in both.

Comment: Firefox tied `-webkit` support to an opt in via `layout.css.prefixes.webkit` in version 44.  I believe they changed that in v49 but that may be part of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I had the code disabled. You should be able to see the problem now.